# Who is the "wicked" one?

Tags: prophecy, nahum

Who is the "wicked counsellor," 'the plotter of evil," in the following verse from The Book of Nahum?

> DKJB Nahum 1:11 "There is one come out of thee, that imagineth evil against Jehovah, **a wicked counsellor.**
>
> NIV Nahum 1:11 "From you, Nineveh, has one come forth who plots evil against the LORD and devises wicked plans."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NIV Study Bible notes says this about "the one who plots evil":

> Possibly the Assyrian king Ashurbanipal (669-627 B.C.), the last great Assyrian emperor, whose western expeditions succeeded in subduing Egypt and to whom King Mannasseh had to submit as a vassal (see 2 Chronicles 33:11-13).

The introductory notes to the book of Nahum in the NIV Study Bible makes this observation:

> In Nahum 3:8-10 the author speaks of the fall of Thebes, which happened in 663 B.C. as already past.  In all three chapters Nahum prophesied Nineveh's fall, which was fulfilled in 612.  Nahum therefore uttered this oracle between 663 and 612, perhaps at the end of this periodsince he represents the fall of Nineveh as imminent.  This wouldplace him during the reign of Josiah and make him a contemporary of Zephaniah and the young Jeremiah.
>
> Assyria (represented by Nineveh, 1:1) had already destroyed Samaria (722-721 B.C.), resulting in the captivity of the northern kingdom of Israel, and posed a present threat to Judah.  The Assyrians were brutally cruel, their kings often being depicted as gloating over the gruesome punishments inflicted on conquered peoples.  They conducted their wars with shocking ferocity, uprooted whole populations as state policy and deported them to other parts of their empire.  The leaders of conquered cities were tortured and horribly mutilated before being executed.  No wonder the dread of Assyria fell on all her neighbours!

The wicked one described by Nahum was probably Ashurbanipal (669-627 B.C.).  Some denominations try to ascribe these events to a modern-day situation where the enemies of God will attack his people in these, the last days.  However, I am not here to speculate, but simply to present historical information regarding the known events between 663 and 612 B.C.  I hope that helps to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

It’s the Assyrian known by many other names and titles

Nineveh was the capital city of the Assyrian Empire also known as the land of Nimrod Micah 5:6. By default anyone coming out of Nineveh was an Assyrian if they were a native.

But it’s not referring to a human, or the Assyrian people, it’s a spirit. A spirit of wickedness, revolt and rebellion against Elohim. We also know it as the antiChrist spirit.

If you look at the Septuagint in Daniel 10:20 where we read in English the prince of Persia in the LXX its the king of the king. If you understand (even if you don’t ascribe to) the divine council and sons of Elohim which later became the gods of the nations, you’ll realize that behind the king was another king or spirit. Paul calls them principalities, powers, rulerships or daimonions. In like manner this wicked one will inhabit a total of seven persons/kings and one of them he will inhabit/possess twice. Rev 17:10,11

He is the serpent of old, satan, the devil, son of perdition, the wicked one, the Assyrian, Lucifer, son of the morning, king of Tyrus. All the other gods/sons-of-elohim gave their powers to him, conspiring against Elohim after their judgment in Psalm 82

“and said to him, “I will give you all this power and glory. It has been handed over to me, and I can give it to whomever I choose.”
‭‭Luke (Luk)‬ ‭4:6‬ ‭CJB‬‬

When I read Nahum 1:11 I read the spirit of antiChrist or satan. He took on in history 6 or 7 times the role of king of the king in an attempt to destroy the seed lineage to prevent the redemption of humanity. So you can read it purely from a material stand point or you can read it with the spiritual dimension in mind. I choose to read it with the spiritual dimension in mind because the spirit behind the king is the one that is truely pulling the strings.

Also the Assyrian the man or the spirit or both were in Egypt at the time of Israel’s captivity.

> “For thus saith the Lord God, My people went down aforetime into Egypt to sojourn there; and the Assyrian oppressed them without cause.”
>   ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭52:4‬ ‭KJV‬‬

He is not limited to just one geographic location as generally are/were the gods of the nations, but he still carries the title. In part because of the cruelty with which the Assyrians treated their enemies but not limited to. So the Assyrian can be the king of Tyre and the Pharoah/king of Egypt. He doesn’t have to be only in one geographic region or attached to only one people